# admob not showing ads on MacOS app released as "iPhone & iPad App"

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, admob, capacitor

The app "[NYC Quiz](https://apps.apple.com/at/app/nyc-quiz/id6474293173)" which contains AdMob ads was automatically released into the Mac store. As you can see in the App store it says "Designed for iPad. Not verified for macOS."

I am just trying to find the cause of this. I suspect that this is expected behaviour and that there might not be a solution yet. Especially since in Admob when creating an App, it is not possible to tick "MacOS" as the OS, only IOS/Android.

Possible causes:

- Admob does not yet support MacOS
- AdMob-CapacitorJS does not yet support MacOS

If any one the two are the cause, maybe someone knows whether there are plans to make it be possible in the future, and if so, when?

I used this library to integrate ads:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob

Maybe a possible solution would be to use Google AdSense inside the WebView. However I am not sure whether this is compliant with the Apple/Google policies. Maybe someone knows more about this?